# How to fix Python error: AttributeError: type object X has no attribute Y

Tags: python, oop

I'm creating a practice python file to better understand object oriented programming and I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ID' has no attribute 'the_other_number'
```

I don't really understand why this happens because when I change the variable like below, it works just fine. I only receive an error when I try to use it in an if statement:

```
ID.the_other_number = 'new_value'
```

Below is my example code that I am trying to fix, any help is appreciated.

```
class ID():
   def __init__(self):
       self.other_number()
       pass

   def other_number(self):
       self.the_other_number = 3111

class ID_2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.update_number()

    def update_number(self):
       if ID.the_other_number > 4:
           print(ID.the_other_number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ID()
   ID_2()
```

I was expecting it to understand what variable is equal to and run the if statement correctly. Also, don't try to make sense of the code, I realize the code doesn't make sense, it is simply an example.

Comment: The indent of your other_number function in your ID class is off by one.

Comment: @BoboDarph Thanks, just fixed it!

Comment: You also use 3 spaces instead of 4 in update_number of ID_2

Answer (score 2):

When you run `ID()` a new instance of the `ID` class is created.  `__init__` calls the `other_number` method of that instance, which assigns the instance attribute `the_other_number`.  Since you don't save that instance anywhere, by assigning the output of `ID()`, it's garbage collected immediately.  The `ID` class does not change.

When you run `ID_2()`, you create an instance of the `ID_2` class and run it's `__init__` method.  That calls the `update_number` method of that instance, which checks `ID._the_other_number`.  `ID` has no `the_other_number` attribute, so an error is raised.

Read the [Python tutorial on Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes), and pay special attention to the difference between class objects and instance objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are making one mistake: You have to understand that `ID` is a class, it's not an object

So, if you want to use the function `ID.the_other_number`, you have to first create an object of `ID`.
So, just add one extra line to your code

```
class ID():
   def __init__(self):
       self.other_number()
       pass

   def other_number(self):
       self.the_other_number = 3111

class ID_2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.update_number()

    def update_number(self):

        # Create one object of class ID - ID_object
        ID_object = ID()

        # Call the function for ID_object
        if ID_object.the_other_number > 4:
           print(ID_object.the_other_number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ID()
   ID_2()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick Haugh 's answer already explains why your code fails to execute the way you expect it.
Absent the issues with indenting, here's how I would modify your code to print the_other_number property of class ID:

```
class ID():
    def __init__(self):
        self.other_number()

    def other_number(self):
        self.the_other_number = 3111
        return self.the_other_number

class ID_2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.update_number()

    def update_number(self):
        id = ID()
        if id.other_number() > 4:
            print(id.the_other_number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ID()
   ID_2()
```